# Is it possible to merge two separate ecto queries?

Tags: elixir, ecto

I am wondering if it is possible to combine two queries together in ecto.

I would like to create a function which takes an ecto query and modifies it depending on the case.

For example, let's imagine we have a `users` table that allows duplicate `usernames` to be entered and a user creates the following query...

```
query = from(u in "users", select: u)
select_all_unique_users(query)
```

I would like the `select_all_unique_users` function to take `query` and add to it, so that it only selects the distinct usernames.

> *this is only an example, I know that I could create a `unique_index` on the table to avoid this in reality =D*

As `query` is a struct under the hood, I figured I could update the `distinct` key do this. This seems to work, however the downside is that it doesn't seem very flexible and looks like it will be hard to implement if I ever want to add a more complicated logic.

Simply put, what I would like to do is create a function that takes a query and adds some more logic to it...

```
iex()> query = from(u in "users", select: u)
#Ecto.Query<from u0 in "users", select: u0>

iex()> select_all_unique_users(query)
#Ecto.Query<from u0 in "users", distinct: [asc: u0.username], select: u0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select_all_unique_users function would be implemented like this:

```
defmodule TestModule do
  def select_all_unique_users(q) do
    from u in q, distinct: u.username
  end
end
```

And you can use it like below:

```
iex(2)> query = from(u in "users", select: u)
#Ecto.Query<from u in "users", select: u>

iex(3)> distinct = TestModule.select_all_unique_users(query)
#Ecto.Query<from u in "users", distinct: [asc: u.username], select: u>
```

I wrapped `select_all_unique_users` in a module I created for the purpose of this answer, but you can place it in any module you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can!

You could go about it like this, supposing you have a `select_all_unique_users/1` function like so:

```
def select_all_unique_users(query) do
  from(u in query, distinct: u.username)
end
```

should do the trick. So, you could then do:

```
# using a defined User schema is preferred over "users". Using
# "users" might cause an error for not being able to sellect all fields
# from table without a schema

iex> q = from(u in User, select: u)
#Ecto.Query<from u in User, select: u>
iex> select_all_unique_users(q)
#Ecto.Query<from u in User, distinct: [asc: u.username], select: u>
```

> Notice that the query from `select_all_unique_users/1` doesn't have another `select` statement. It's because only one `select` expression is allowed. So, if you wanted to select different attributes on your different queries, you might want to add that in `select_all_unique_users/1` or any other functions you may have that base on the `from(u in User)`